# Parsing special characters from JSON string in JS

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, special-characters

Today, while I was working with some ajax requests, I encountered really strange issue.
After sending simple request, server response in JSON format looks like below:

```
{
coach_id: "172"
email: "foo@bar.com"
focus_area: "Ke da\nMetrics"
id: "433"
success_metrics: "\"Calm\""
user_id: "809"
}
```

I want to use this object as data for pure.js template (it doesn't matter, as it's problem itself, not in template system).

```
$('#new-client').directives({
    '#client-email@value' : 'email',
    '#client-focus' : 'focus_area',
    '#client-success' : 'success_metrics'
}).render(myObject);
```

Email as simple input, focus_area and success_metrics as textareas.

However, I'm not able to get my object special characters parsed properly.

For example "Ke da\nMetrics" should looks:
"Ke da
Metrics"

I already tried encoding it, replacing characters etc. but with no effect.

Any hints?

Whole object after stringifying:

```
{
    "id": "433",
    "coach_id": "172",
    "organization_id": "33",
    "user_id": "809",
    "start_date": "0202-02-02",
    "sessions_allotment": "5",
    "sessions_frequency": "TwiceAMonth",
    "sessions_frequency_other": "None",
    "tags": "KeTag,SanJose",
    "focus_area": "\\' \\\" Ke da\\nMetrics",
    "success_metrics": "\\\"Calm\\\"",
    "organization_level": "Grand P",
    "bill_rate": "34",
    "first_name": "Ke",
    "last_name": "Da",
    "email": "keda@mailinator.com",
    "coach_first_name": "Dawn",
    "coach_last_name": "Gilbert"
}
```

Here's console log http://screenshu.com/static/uploads/temporary/6n/0n/f2/2vt72y.jpg

Comment: ...so basically your question is about string-escaping in JSON? Is the newline character not resolved?

Comment: That's no valid JSON, you'd need to enclose property names in quotes, too.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us the code, from receiving the server response to using the parsed object.

Comment: Use valid JSON as Bergi said, and make use of the online validator ( http://jsonlint.com/ )

Comment: @LoSauer Yes, because my object cannot be parsed properly and newline is not showing up.

JSON is valid, I just pasted console log, sorry for misunderstanding. I posted whole object below.

Comment: Looks like you are stringifying JSON, instead of an object. Where is the code that is calling `JSON.stringify`?

Answer (score 0):

\n is the Unix line ending.

I'm not sure if a line ending is what you desire but much like \"Calm\" would print:

```
"Calm"
```

Then "Ke da\nMetrics" would print:

```
Ke da
Metrics
```

So - in your case - without going on a man-hunt to find out why there is a line-ending in the value - you could use this code:

```
myObject.focus_area = myObject.focus_area.replace(/\n/g, '');
$('#new-client').directives({
    '#client-email@value' : 'email',
    '#client-focus' : 'focus_area',
    '#client-success' : 'success_metrics'
}).render(myObject);
```

As I say - the problem is with server encoding of your value - ideally the JSON would not contain the \n.

---

Thinking about above - it's probably a UTF8 issue - sorry bad answer above...

If you try loading the JSON using utf8 as the encoding does the newline still showup?

Comment: Yes, I want every \n to print proper new line instead of it's escaped version.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions would be to use [JavaScript functions with directives](http://beebole.com/pure/documentation/using-js-functions-with-directives/) and use some 
filter method removing / replacing / ... all unwanted characters from input JSON object (e.g. to remove `\n` or replace `\n` with space; that can be done using regular expressions)

You can have more *filtering* functions (each performing specific type of filtering) and chain them together in functions with directives.

Assuming your filter methods would be called `filter(arg)` and `otherFilter(arg)`, your directive could be as follows:

```
$('#new-client').directives({
    '#client-email@value' : function(arg) { 
         return filter(arg.context.email); 
    },
    '#client-focus' : function(arg) { 
         return filter(arg.context.focus_area); 
    },
    '#client-success' : function(arg) { 
         return otherFitler(filter(arg.context.success_metrics)); 
    }
}).render(myObject);
```

I hope that will help.